# How to split HTTP header in C?

Tags: c, strtok, string.h

I receive HTTP request at socket.

I want to split HTTP request at header and content.

So, I tried this source.

```c
//p is char* type, response too
p = strtok(response, "\r\n\r\n");
while(NULL != p){
    printf("%s\n", p);
    p  = strtok(NULL, "\r\n\r\n");
}
```

But `strtok()` replaced `"\r\n"` by `NULL` too.

I want replace only `"\r\n\r\n"`.

How should I?

Comment: Just do it manually not a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`strstr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html)

```
//p1 is char* type, response and p2 too
p1 = response;
p2 = strstr(response, "\r\n\r\n");
while(NULL != p2){
    printf("%.*s\n", p2 - p1, p1);
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = strstr(p2 + 1, "\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: .. and on that same site, you can read [why you are using `strtok` wrong](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html)

Comment: I want to return Header or Content too. How can return Header or content?

Comment: to return something to the caller, copy it to the destination address (make sure it has enough space); or allocate memory and return that (make sure to free it when it's no longer needed).